# SQL AVG (average) returns lots of digits

Tags: mysql, sql, database, average

When I do something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(Price) FROM Product WHERE ProductName = 'Shoe';
```

the SQL returns something like this: `6,5934348324242`

An average number with a lot of digits.

Is it possible to do something in the query so the query returns 2/3 digits (for example: 6,59) instead of 10+ digits?

I am using `MySql`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert it to a decimal:

```
SELECT cast(AVG(Price) as decimal(6, 2))
FROM Product
WHERE ProductName = 'Shoe';
```

Comment: Wow, is it possible to cast SQL-queries... Lol.. They didn't tell us that at school :s.. Going to test it out!

Comment: This works! Can someone explain me why u use (6,2)? Doesn't 6 mean the total digits, and the 2; the digits after the comma?

Comment: @xVizzi . . . Yes, that is what those mean.  I chose them as arbitrary values that seemed to fit with your data.